# Django and uploading Media files to AWS S3 for users in app to view

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework, media

this might be a vague question but I am developing an app where users can upload files (mainly videos and pictures). Users can create groups and upload their images to the group and anyone in the group can view these files.  I have the AWS S3 configured and working however, Aws recommends to keep the bucket **Private**.

if the bucket is private, is the only way to allow access for users to view content (maybe uploaded by friends VIA pre-signed urls?)

is it necessary to even make the bucket private. I see tutorials and they usually have the bucket settings to public. this means that any person that has a hold of the url can access an image. Lets say user 1 uploads to group xyz. only members of xyz should be able to access that image.

implementing unique identifiers for images will make it tough for someone to get access to that image but not impossible. would this be the better approach or having django generate signed URLS everytime a user wants to view a certain image? I feel like this is overkill for a photosharing app.

3. are there any other ways to add security?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily buckets needs to be public. You can access the private files using url and keep it private. You may look at signature 4 security of s3. You can generate a url for files with params containing access keys with expiration time(key is different each time). Only having the access keys with the url private files are accessible. If the default ACL is private , DRF automatically adds the keys in the url.

Comment: Thank you. This is I think what I was looking for. Is it possible for you to link me to the documentation/tutorial . It would be helpful!